# Why does my code not compile under Foundry when I use remappings with overlapping paths?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, foundry, forge

I want the following import in `src`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
```

This is my current `remappings.txt` that doesn't work correctly.

```
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Foundry. Or at least an incompatibility with how the [Solidity compiler processes remappings](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/path-resolution.html#import-remapping). For solc your remappings are perfectly fine.

This will compile just fine (assuming that your file is called `test.sol`):

```bash
mkdir lib/
cd lib/
git clone https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
git clone https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable

solc test.sol --bin $(cat remappings.txt)
```

---

Foundry apparently is ignoring the rule that when multiple remappings match, the one with the longest prefix should be chosen. As a result it uses the first rule in your `remappings.txt` for all imports.

I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/new?assignees=&labels=T-bug&template=BUG-FORM.yml) (unless somebody has already filed an issue about this). In the meantime, a workaround would be to use a different prefix. For example you could replace

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
```

with

```
import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
```

and then change your remappings to:

```
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/
```

Comment: Yep, this used to be a bug in Foundry. I opened a GitHub issue for it here: [overlapping nested remappings are not resolved](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/5447). However, it should be fixed now - just run `foundryup`.